# Google App Engine YAML not providing env variable

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm setting up a Java servlet on Google App Engine. Working out alright but now I'm trying to set up a database within Google Cloud. I'm provided with a template that suggests that I should enter my app.yaml-file and enter something like this:

```
env_variables:
    DB_URL: 'some.url.to.a.db'
```

Later I should call this variable using:

```
String dbUrl = System.getenv("DB_URL");
```

This gives me null everytime that I try it out.

This is the site that has shown me how to define the env-variables. Is there anything obvious I have misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is valid. It should work on App Engine Flexible instance. For me it works with

```
runtime: java
vm: true
```

But environment variables declared in the app.yaml will not be seen if you use jetty:run on local machine. So this is not a good solution for configuring sql. I advise to look an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/flexible/cloudsql). Note, that it use new App Engine environment and **vm:true** is deprecated.

```
runtime: java
env: flex
```

Comment: I am not using vm: true and this is not failing due to being deployed on localhost. I use mvn:appengine deploy for deployment.

Comment: Could you provide full content of app.yaml? And are you using appengine-web.xml?